# How to get access to the Hibernate Statistics

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jakarta-ee

So in my `persistence.xml` I turned on `hibernate.generate_statistics`.

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

My question is how do I access them?  Where do the statistics go?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your dao service you can go:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
SessionStatistics sessionStats = session.getStatistics();
Statistics stats = this.sessionFactory.getStatistics();
```

Answer (score 13):

i would rather use [Hibernate Statistics published via JMX](http://www.hibernate.org/216.html) if you use spring you can make it real easy with [Hibernate Statistics MBean with Spring](http://raibledesigns.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=HibernateJMX)

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways you can access the Hibernate Statistics:

## Programatically

If you want to get the [`Statistics`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statistics/) object in your application, you can do it as follows:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

Statistics statistics = session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
```

## Logging

If you want to log the `Statistics` report, you need to add the following log configuration entry:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener" level="info"/>
```

## JMX

You can also expose the `Statistics` object via JMX by setting the [`hibernate.jmx.enabled`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statistics-jmx/) property.

For this, you need to set the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jmx.enabled" value="true"/>
```

And locate the `org.hibernate.core` MBean package in your JMX client application.

Comment: From Operations point of view: JMX is the best option since APM tools can collect the data from JMX; From Development point of view, in local box the JConsole tool from JDK can view the data easily

Answer (score 4):

You can also add a logger for it.
See; http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-activate-hibernate-statistics-to-analyze-performance-issues/

```
<!--Hibernate Statistics-->
            <logger category="org.hibernate.stat" use-parent-handlers="true">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
```

Answer (score 2):

In our application we published it via JMX and to make it complete we hat to kind of manually [add the criteria query data using aspects](http://hons82.blogspot.com/2011/12/hibernate-statisctics-criteria-queries.html)